# Google Sheets' QUERY to find containing at end of string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

How do I indicate contains "xyz" when it is the end of a string but not in the middle in a query, for example

`xyzabc` should return false
`abcxyz` should return true

in the query results.

Comment: can you share more information, a copy of your file or screenshots can help. I can say use something like =if(right(cell,3)="xyz",TRUE,FALSE); within the query but I don't know if that will works in your case, I can test if you share a copy of your file.

Comment: @MarioR. here is an example... I want to find text containing "xyz" and "xyz placeholder" but I do not want to find text containing "xyzabc" basically I am looking for a distinct word and I wanted to do it right in the query function.

Answer (score 1):

in `QUERY` you can use `ends with` like:

```
=QUERY(A:D, "select A,B where D ends with 'xyz'", 0
```

**https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where**